# Unable to install software using apt-get in Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, apt, aptitude

I'm trying to install some software in my Ubuntu Server 12.04 installation, but whenever I try to install it using apt-get or aptitude, I would usually get an error message like this:

```
E: unable to locate package postgresql-plperl-9.0
E: couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-plperl-9.0'
```

The contents of my /etc/apt/sources.list file is (all of it are uncommented):

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
```

Any help on why I am encountering this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need that specific version, you should use the Postgresql APT repos in addition to the Ubuntu repos.

The are located at http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/

The README file has instructions for using it.

Proof, using that old build on a new Ubuntu 14.04 system:

```
# grep DESC /etc/lsb-release ; apt-cache show postgresql-plperl-9.0
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
Package: postgresql-plperl-9.0
Source: postgresql-9.0
Version: 9.0.18-1.pgdg14.04+1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no package named `postgresql-plperl-9.0` available in plain ubuntu.

Also Ubuntu 12.04 only contains `postgresql-8.4` and `postgresql-9.1`.

If this package is included in any other package source then you have to include this.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was distracted by other issues, but it seems that it extended to other software as well. For example, when I tried to install gcc today, but when I tried to install it using apt-get, I received: 'Package gcc is not available, but is referred to by another package along with an explanation that it might be missing and that gcc has no installation candidate.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to run:

```
apt-get update
```

Before attempting to install the software with apt-get install, to ensure that the right package names, locations and dependency lists are set up on your machine before it tries to grab all the packages.

Seems simple but it's fixed problems with similar errors for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did a check and realized that the extra lines in the sources.list file to be missing the "universe" line at the end of the list.

So I added it to something like this:

deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu precise main universe 
   and deb-src http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu precise main universe

ran `apt-get update` , and it works.